# Weighted order of List with Null

Tags: java, arraylist, null, comparator

I've been trying to implement a `Comparator` class which should order a list based on weight of position. I will explain what I should accomplish.

Suppose I have an `ArrayList<T>`. This array list has always a fixed size, filling other slot with `null` values.

```java
//fixed size = 3
T myObj1, myObj2;
[myObj1, null, myObj2];
```

In this example, `myObj2 < myObj1`, since it is stored in a slot whose position value is less than the first.

An ordering comparator should give this output:

```java
//fixed size = 3
T myObj1, myObj2;
[myObj1, myObj2, null];
```

Other examples:

```java
//fixed size = 7;
T myObj1, myObj2, myObj3, myObj4;
INPUT = [myObj1, null, null, myObj4, myObj3, myObj2, null];
RESULT = [myObj1, myObj4, myObj3, myObj2, null, null, null];
```

I thought about using a`Comparator<T>`(The T is a specific class, it does not need to be general actually); is there a way to replicate such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always make nulls return > 0 in a comparator

```
if (one == null && two == null) {
    return 0;
} else if (two == null) {
    return -1;
} if (one == null) {
    return 1;
} else {
   //Compare logic...
}
```

This says nulls are "bigger" than non-null values

Comment: I will try this in my comparator!

Comment: The doubt was about keeping track of the already present order in my Array list (in the second example `myObj1 > myObj4` because it appears in first position whereas obj4 in 4th position). EDIT: nvm I figured out.

Comment: Note that you can shortcut that using `Comparator.nullsFirst(...)` (or `nullsLast(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own comparator logic, it is usually simpler to use one of the helper methods such as [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-).

```java
> List<Integer> foo = Arrays.asList(1, null, 2, null, 1, null);
> Collections.sort(foo, Comparator.comparing(x -> x == null ? 1 : 0));
> foo
[1, 2, 1, null, null, null]
```

This way the sort is done as if non-null elements are all 0, and nulls are 1, so the nulls will appear after the non-nulls when they are sorted. The non-null elements will remain in their original order, because [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) is stable.

For this specific case as @Zabuza notes, the helper method [`Comparator.nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) does exactly the right thing; the argument is `null` because there is no "fallback" comparator we want to use for non-null elements.

```java
> Collections.sort(foo, Comparator.nullsLast(null));
```

That said, this solution takes O(n log n) time for a list of length n, when a two-pointer solution could solve the same problem in O(n) time.

Comment: Note that there is `Comparators.nullsFirst(...)` and `nullsLast(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in need, I figured it out thanks to @tomgeraghty3

```java
public class TComparator implements Comparator<T> {
    public int compare(T r1, T r2) {
        if (r1 == null && r2 == null) {
            return 0;
        } else if (r2 == null) {
            return -1;
        } if (r1 == null) {
            return 1;
        } else {
           return 1;
        }
    }
}
```